# Oracle remove and place (re-install) database on 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I need to put together a plan to execute some change scripts to a Oracle 10g database, which will add some values, change some values a drop a table and create a new table.

I have a step for creating a DMP of the original database before the changes and for running a script that will execute all the changes. 
But I need a back-out plan if things go wrong.
I was wondering what is the bets step(s) to drop the database and import the old DMP file?

I know about the sqlplus command:

```
imp <touser>/<password>@<host_address>/<service> file=<filename>.dmp fromuser=<fromuser> touser=<touser> log=backup_import.log
```

But what is the best way to drop the existing database? Is it just

```
drop user <schema_user> cascade;
```

Thanks in advance.

K

Comment: `imp` is not a "*SQLPlus*" command. It's a commandline tool.

Comment: Do you really want to drop "the database"? Note that a "database" in Oracle is basically the whole installation, not just a single "namespace" inside the system (as e.g. in Postgres or SQL Server). It seems you just want to drop the *schema* (=user). In that case, `drop user ... cascade` *is* the best option.

Comment: ... as long as you're really sure you have a good and complete dump of everything you'll need. You'd also need to recreate the user with all its non-table privileges before running the import. You should look at [datapump `expdp`/`impdp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/part_dp.htm#i436481) rather than the older `exp`/`imp` though, since you're on 10g.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to drop database is to use DBCA graphic tool. Or you can use this sequence of commands:

```
shutdown immediate 
startup exclusive mount
alter system enable restricted session;
drop database;
```

But **instead** I suggest using RMAN backup and restore.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use restore points for your back-out plan. Before you start your changes, issue a

```
create restore point insert_meaningful_name;
```

Then apply all your changes. When something goes wrong, issue a

```
flashback database to restore point insert_meaningful_name;
```

This will revert your database to the exact same state it had when you created the restore point.

Please note that you need SYS-privileges to use restore points and flashback database.